# How to pass libraries through Google CAJA?

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, google-caja

Does anyone know if I can configure Google Caja, so it let some exact libraries to work and not being sanitized? 
I have my own CAJA server, and application based on NodeJS. I'm passing to Google CAJA users code, which will be mostly related to charts and graphs, but all libraries functions (like d3js, chart.js) are blocked by CAJA.
All libraries are go through Caja and connect to user's document without errors, but if users request any feature of library (For example `d3.select("body").append("svg")` ) then it is showing errors, like `this * is not a function`. Does anyone know any method?

PS I know about URI Policy, but it seems that it just controls all stuff, that is going out of same origin domain names, whenever eeven if library is passed through uriPolicy, it is still being checked by Caja.

Comment: Have you seen the mitigate attribute of the uriPolicy?

Comment: Hi! Yes I've found it, unfortunately I couldn't make it work. I couldn't find any documentation for it, i found it in the source code of caja itself. I would be very thankful if you have some information on how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can return url to a pre-mitigated/pre-cajoled/trusted version of the library from the uriPolicy.mitigate function. You can just check the libraries url and if it matches you return the premitigated URL else you return null. For example:

```
var uriPolicy = {
    mitigate: function(uri) {
        if(/jquery\.js/.test(uri))
            return urlToMyJquery.js;
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and what if I want to connect something not from pre-trusted list? For example D3.js. How can I get it from my own storage?

Comment: You can basically return url to any resource be it mitigated or not. Although an unmitigated one may open up your app to security risks so be very careful